# Using Summer note to edit HTML + CSS that's stored in Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, summernote

I am using summer note to access my SQL Database and retrieve a field called page_details that is currently storing html and css of pages created in summer note.

I'm able to create pages perfectly fine and upload the html and css into the database with no issue, but when I try and edit them in summer note some of the pages that were created you cant edit, where as some can be edited perfectly fine.

The ones that you can't not edit throw an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 
[Uncaught SyntaxError: Image with part of Source code causing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKixo.png)

The pages that open perfectly fine also start with `<h1>` Any Idea's on how to fix this error?

```
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM page WHERE page_id=:page_id');
            $page_id = $_GET['page_id'];
            $stmt->bindParam(':page_id',$page_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
             $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              extract($row);
            }
            ?>
                    <form action="save_page.php?page_id=<?echo $row['page_id'];?> " autocomplete="off" method="post">
            <textarea id="summernote" name="summernote" ></textarea>
                                 <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="update_page" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Update Page</button>
            </form>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', '<? echo $row['page_details'];?>');


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.summernote').summernote({
            height: 200
        });


        $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
            var summernoteContent = $('.summernote').summernote('code');
            $('#result').val(summernoteContent);
        });

    });


    </script>



This Fixed the syntax error: 
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', `<? echo $row["page_details"];?>`);
```

Comment: It's a syntax error. Either have single quotes within double quotes or double quotes within single quotes. `$('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', "<? echo $row['page_details'];?>");`

Comment: @random didn't fix the syntax error I am getting. "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: Try `$('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', '<? echo $row[' + page_details + '];?>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `page_details` is a variable, you can use template literals.

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', `<? echo $row[${page_details}];?>`);
```

Comment: I was able to modify the code you had provided and it's now working! Thank you! I never thought about using template literals! ```$('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', `<? echo $row["page_details"];?>`);```